# Validate if object is empty from values in an array - Javascript

Tags: javascript, validation

I have a data for businesses like below:

```
{
    "business": {
        "type": [
            "LLC",
            "Corporation"
        ],
        "LLC": {
            "status": "active",
            "profits": 1000000,
            "period": "yearly"
        },
        "corporation": {},
        "partnership": {}
    }
}
```

How do I validate the "corporation" object, so if the "type" array contains the string "Corporation", the "corporation" object cannot be empty?

I've tried using validate.js to check if it is empty, it works but I can't specifically put the strings inside the type array to validate it.

```
const validate = require('validate.js');
if (validate.isEmpty(business.LLC)) {
    return wrapper.error('fail', 'Object is empty');
}
```

Thank you very much for the help

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? Like separating the steps necessary: Does an array contain a given string? Are there any properties in an object?

Comment: Edited, my bad. That's what I've tried so far.

Comment: Your edit does nothing of the necessary steps. It doesn't check the content of `type` or `corporation`

Comment: Yeah I just realised what I was supposed to do because of dinesh's answer below, and then I put my own validation. I think it'll affect the api's performance if I need to check more business types but it'll do for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let object = {
    "business": {
        "type": [
            "LLC",
            "Corporation"
        ],
        "LLC": {
            "status": "active",
            "profits": 1000000,
            "period": "yearly"
        },
        "corporation": {},
        "partnership": {}
    }
}
```

Use **includes** to check the elements inside array,

```
object.business.type.includes("Corporation")
```

Comment: OMG I haven't thought about this! I should've checked the array first and then I can use my own validation above, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out and didn't realise as well, thank you [dinesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14346235/dinesh-oz) for your answer!

So what I need to do is to check the array first and then check the objects below.

```
if (payload.business.type.includes('Corporation')) {
      if (validate.isEmpty(payload.business.corporation)) {
        return wrapper.error('fail', 'Object is empty');
      }
    }
```